# Why are these glsl attributes being “optimized out”

Tags: graphics, glsl, vulkan

I was following a point light shadow mapping example by Sascha Williems and encountered an issue where my inputted attributes were not being accepted by the shader. Checking the shader decompiler in renderdoc shows that glsl had optimized out all of the inputs from the shader. This makes sense, since attributes 1-3 are unused, but attribute 0 is used but it still being optimized out.

```
#version 450

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 color;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 normal;
layout(location = 3) in vec2 uv;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 outPos;

struct PointLight {
    vec4 position;
    vec4 color;
};

layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform GlobalUbo {
    mat4 projection;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 inverseView;
    vec4 ambientLightColor;
    PointLight pointLights[10];
    int numLights;
} ubo;

layout(push_constant) uniform Push {
    mat4 modelMatrix;
    mat4 viewMatrix;
} push;

void main() {
    vec4 positionWorld = push.modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = ubo.projection * push.viewMatrix * positionWorld;
    outPos = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Edit: Fragment Shader

```
#version 450

layout(location = 0) out float outFragColor;

layout(location = 0) in vec4 inPos;

struct PointLight {
    vec4 position;
    vec4 color;
};

layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform GlobalUbo {
    mat4 projection;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 inverseView;
    vec4 ambientLightColor;
    PointLight pointLights[10];
    int numLights;
} ubo;

void main()
{
    vec3 lightVec = inPos.xyz - ubo.pointLights[0].xyz;
    outFragColor = length(lightVec);
}
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 `ubo` is not optimized out, since it is used in `gl_Position`, however the whole problem I am having is that the compiler IS optimizing out `position` for some reason, as noticed by both the vulkan validation warnings and renderdocs shader decompiler.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes I do have a fragment shader, but how are you certain that the fragment shader is the problem and not the vertex shader?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I have added my fragment shader to the post, I do not believe the problem is with the fragment shader though since it is compiled seperately from the vertex shader, it shouldn’t be effecting the vertex shaders compiling process and cause some values to be optimized out.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be related to the shader code. Are you sure that the files are loaded, compiled and linked correctly?

Comment: We can't see in your head. How do you specifically know the compiler is optimizing it out? What are the validation warnings? What tooling are you using to compile it? Make a minimal verifiable example; do not include other inputs and outputs and other cruft in the code you show others unless the problem disappears without them.